# Are there any examples of using cloud-init offline (or without cloud hosting)?

Tags: cloud, cloud-init

**Note:** This is **NOT** a Raspberry Pi specific question. It is a Linux System Administration question. Please do not try to have it removed from Server Fault.

I see many "Hello, World" level demos that are specific to [insert cloud hosting platform here], but none that are geared to being used on a single local machine. I was encouraged to see that [Raspbian has cloud-init in its repository](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list/item/54-raspbian-admin#c). That is exactly [what I want to do](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.9/topics/examples.html#run-commands-on-first-boot). However, I cannot find any information on how to do it without a AWS, OpenStack, etc.

So, I guess what I really want to know is after you `apt-get install cloud-init`, where do you put your config/userdata?

---

**Update:** I found some info on the [NoCloud datasource](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.9/topics/datasources/nocloud.html), but I cannot add a volume labeled `cidata`. So, that is out for me. (The volume that will hold my user-data is labeled `boot`.)

Comment: Then you'll need to change the volume label. Or you could even put such a volume on your SD card. But, why is this not a Raspberry Pi question?

Comment: It's not an RPi question because: 1. It's not exclusive to RPi. If I were doing this on my Lenovo laptop, it wouldn't be a Lenovo question. It'd still be a cloud-init question. 2. There are exactly zero people using cloud-init on an RPi as of today.

Comment: Those are both possible directions. But I'm looking for others. Both of those options are going to have unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1):

With the [current version of cloud-init](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/17.2/topics/datasources/nocloud.html) you can use smbios options to provide `user-data` and `meta-data`. There is also an example for the case  you have a local HTTP Server providing these files:

```
-smbios type=1,serial=ds=nocloud-net;s=http://10.10.0.1:8000/
```

Comment: Sadly, my distro has cloud-init 0.7.9 and I can't figure out how to build/install a more recent version. Also, having an external web server as a requirement is undesirable. One of the things I'd like to configure is wifi settings.

Comment: Making progress! https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845732/117471

Answer (score 0):

I have VMs in premisses configured pretty much like [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-kvm-on-centos-7-rhel-7-headless-server/) explains.