# Is it possible to use cloud-init without touching the TFTP config and without a dedicated volume?

Tags: cloud-init

We are currently deploying bare-metal machines using Kickstart scripts. Therefore, I believe we cannot use dedicated volumes labelled "CIDATA".

For reasons specific outside the scope of this question, we cannot change the iPxe script returned by the TFTP server. Therefore, we cannot add arguments to the kernel command line.

Since the machines are bare-metal machines, I don't think that we can change the SMBIOS serial number.

If I believe the cloud-init [documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/datasources/nocloud.html#datasource-nocloud) and the question asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/897610/are-there-any-examples-of-using-cloud-init-offline-or-without-cloud-hosting), I think that our situation is pretty much *hopeless*.

Does anyone know a possible *smart* way to still use cloud-init in such a case?
Or did I miss something?